# How to sum a list of numbers stored as strings

Tags: python

Having a list of numbers stored as strings how do I find their sum?

This is what I'm trying right now:

```
numbers = ['1', '3', '7']
result = sum(int(numbers))
```

but this gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    result = sum(int(numbers))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

I understand that I cannot force the list to be a number, but I can't think of a fix.

Answer (score 8):

`int(numbers)` is trying to convert the list to an integer, which obviously won't work. And if you had somehow been able to convert the list to an integer, `sum(int(numbers))` would then try to get the sum of that integer, which doesn't make sense either; you sum a collection of numbers, not a single one.

Instead, use the function [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
result = sum(map(int, numbers))
```

That'll take each item in the list, convert it to an integer and sum the results.

Answer (score 5):

If you prefer a less functional style, you can use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions)

```
result = sum(int(x) for x in numbers))
```