# result=sum(staffSalary) TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python

I am trying to sum the staff salary in a float with 2 digits after the dot in the code below but gave me that error.

I understand the type of error but unfortunately, I don't know how to fix it. I am trying different ways and it comes with the same error.

```
staffName=[]
staffSalary=[]
for name in range(0,5):
    print('Enter staff name:')
    staffName.append(input())
for salary in range(0,5):
    print('Enter salary:')
    staffSalary.append("{:.2f}".format(float(input())))
print('Staff details entered:\n')
for i in range(0,5):
    print(staffName[i], ' ', staffSalary[i])

result=sum(staffSalary)
print('\nTotal salary amount is: ', result)

totalIncrease=(result * 10) / 100 + result
print('Total salary amount with 10% increase: ',totalIncrease)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376464/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-str-and-int)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sum a list of numbers stored as strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30744195/how-to-sum-a-list-of-numbers-stored-as-strings)

Answer (score 0):

In your line `staffSalary.append("{:.2f}".format(float(input())))`, it looks like you are taking the input and converting it to a float (that sounds right) but then you are turning that into a string. So what you finally add to your list is a string, not a float.

I think you just want `staffSalary.append(float(input())`. Then the list will have all items that are floats. When you have a string later that includes those numbers, you can do some string-transformations then.

Comment: as pointed out your floating number is formatted as a string. If your attempt is truncate or rounding the number use the ```math``` module or brute force ```float("{:.2f}".format(float(input())))```

Comment: @cards Python has a perfectly fine `round()` function. A better solution would be `round(float(input()), 2)`.